# Updating Router components on Global state changes in services

Tags: angular, angular-routing

My Angular application has a `GlobalContext` service and a list of components such as `ComponentA`, `ComponentB`, `ComponentC` and so on. Each of the component is configured to be rendered for a specific route using Angular Router. Now when a state has been changed in the GlobalContext service I want the currently rendered Component among the list of router Components such as ComponentA, ComponentB to be updated.

so How can I get the current instance of the component attached to the router and re-render it to account for the changes made in the GlobalContext. Or Any Idiomatic way in Angular to approach this strategy.

Comment: In a parent component to these routes why not listen to changes of the state with an observable and trigger a route change when the state changes?

Comment: @MichaelSolati why a route change is required. I just want to re-render by current route..

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you meant when you said re-render. Do you want the component to stay the same while the content changes?

Comment: yes exactly..  I just need to update the currently rendered component via the router.

Comment: Are you storing your state as an observable in your service? If you did you could just subscribe to it and update the state of your local component.

Comment: so all router components must subscribe to the Observable on creation and unsubscribe when removed from router?

Comment: That's how I would do it, yea.